# TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array being filtered and reduce but I am having an error in reduce.

```
   getPageComponents(title: string) {
    this.pageComponents = [];
     const pageBlock = this.pageComponents.filter((val) => {
       if (val.page_title === title) {
         return val;
       }
     });

     return pageBlock.reduce(value => value);
   }
```

And i'm having this error below. What could be wrong in reduce?

[image]

Comment: reduce takes an initial value for the returned result. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

What the error says, is that the `pageBlock` array is empty, so he don't know what he should return from the `reduce` function.

You need to pass the starting value as second parameter of the `reduce` function.
for example,

```
return pageBlock.reduce(value => value, null);
```

Just want to point you, that what you currently do in your reduce function is return the first value, and ignore the others.. it is what you want? if so, you can just use

```
return pageBlock[0]
```

--- ABOUT HOW TO USE THE REDUCE FUNCTION ---

The `reduce` function receive a callback with 2 arguments, and a starting value.
it will iterate through the array as following:

- **step 1:** callback(initialValue, array[0])
- **step 2:** callback(theResultFromStep1, array[1])
- **step 3:** callback(theResultFromStep2, array[2])
- ....
- **step N:** callback(theResultFromStep(N-1), array[N-1])

then return the result of the last step.
for example:

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0);
```

will return the sum of array values (suppose its all a numbers)

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a+b, "");
```

will concat all the array values in one string `(same as arr.join(''))`;

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a*b, 0);
```

will return the multiplication of all array values (suppose they all are numbers)

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a, null);
```

will return the first array value, or null if empty

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => b, 0);
```

will return the last array value, or null if empty

etc.

Comment: Yes actually I want to return the first value. Thanks for this. A big help. :)

Comment: Always welcome ) . so I really not see a problem to use `pageBlock[0]` or `pageBlock.shift()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add second parameter for inital value

```
 return pageBlock.reduce(value => value, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are trying to reduce an empty array, this is the reason you're getting this error.**

Your assigning this.pageComponents to an empty array and filtering it. so it will return []. So the pageBlock has [] value. And when you try to reduce pageBlock, it will throw this error.

```
getPageComponents(title: string) {
    this.pageComponents = [];  
     const pageBlock = this.pageComponents.filter((val) => {
       if (val.page_title === title) {
         return val;
       }
     });

 return pageBlock.reduce(value => value);
```

}

Comment: There is no problem to filter an empty array.. it's will just return empty array. The problem is to reduce an empty array

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to return array, so you must pass second parameter in reduce function

```
getPageComponents(title: string) {
    this.pageComponents = [];
     const pageBlock = this.pageComponents.filter((val) => {
     return val.page_title === title
     });

 return pageBlock.reduce(value => value, []);
```

Comment: yeah it returns an empty array, because you are filtering an empty array.

Comment: you can get reference here, (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqpujj)